# get animated value from ValueAnimator without starting the animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-pagetransformer

Is it possible to get animated value from `ValueAnimator` without starting the animation? I do have start and target color.

I have a `PageTransformer` and I want to set background color based on page position. so I want to change background color as the page slides. (not after the page slides)

Is it possible to use `ValueAnimator` without overhead of starting animation?

---

A simple example of what i want

Lets say start value is 0 and target value is 100. animation duration is 500ms.

When i pass 53ms it should output (53/500)*(100).

Now this is a simple example, how do i do it for a color?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How can you have an animated value without starting the animation? If you aren't animating the value, then you can't get an animated value. Are you asking if you can "animate" a value without also modifying a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be writing not exactly about animation, but about interpolation. To get a color value interpolated like you described, you can use `ArgbEvaluator`. This is pretty much what animator does internally and you can use that in page sliding animation without any additional animator.

```
ArgbAnimator evaluator = new ArgbAnimator();
float fraction = 0.53f;    // value between 0.0f and 1.0f
int color1 = Color.RED, color2 = Color.GREEN;
int interpolatedColor = evaluator.evaluate(fraction, color1, color2);
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for! thanks a lot.